# How do I include IniReader class for use in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I'm receiving the following error in CakePhp:

> Fatal Error Error: Class 'IniReader' not found

I'm trying to use the IniReader functionality described here:

http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-IniReader.html

I'm trying to include it using the following:

```
App::uses('IniReader', 'Utility');
$INI_OPTIONS = new IniReader(APP.'Config/plugin.ini');
```

Can anyone help me with the proper way to load this class for use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to load the class is:

```
App::uses('IniReader', 'Configure');
```